# vba userform multiple column copy and paste in sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to build up a userform/ user interface where I can copy in data from SAP (in Excel format) which have many columns. By mouse click on a button, selected columns should be copied into a specific table sheet.
During my research I could only find userform where single columns could be copied into an other worksheet.

Comment: So start by posting the code you've found and what's stopping you from adapting it to your particular problem. And please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To clarify.. you want to be able to copy SAP extract data as multiple columns - **from Excel** - via a userform - **into Excel**?

Comment: @Miqi180 I'm sorry for this, I'm new in this forum and I need to larn it.

Comment: @CLR Yes, the problem is that there are many comulns that I dont need in the sheet and I want just an interface where I can copy all the data inside and the macro should only copy specific columns into a choosen sheet.

Comment: [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513) should help you understand why we can't answer this post on this forum.